# Pass function string as type parameter literal string

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I need to pass a string to a type and use it as a literal string.

What must i change, that the scope string argument is used in the UnprefixKeys-Utility?

It should use the functions scope argument, without adding an extra parameter like `vars<T, Scope>(...`

Example:

```
function vars<T>(scope: string, vars: UnprefixKeys<T, '--XXX-'>): T {
                                                      ^^^^^^^^  this should be replaced
                                                                with the scope var
  //...
  return <T>result
}

type SomeType = {
  '--YYY-a': number
  '--YYY-b': number
}

vars<SomeType>('--YYY-', {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
})

// type utilities (they work)
type UnprefixKey<K extends PropertyKey, Prefix extends string>
  = K extends `${Prefix}${infer P}` ? P : K

type UnprefixKeys<T, Prefix extends string> = {
  [K in keyof T as UnprefixKey<K, Prefix>]: T[K]
}
```

The return type should be:

```json
{
  '--YYY-: number,
  '--YYY-: number,
}
```

But it is currently (cause of fixed string `--XXX-`)

```json
{
  '--XXX-: number,
  '--XXX-: number,
}
```

Comment: *"...without adding an extra parameter like `vars<T, Scope>(...`"* Why not? That's how you do it. With that limitation, you can't do it.

Comment: It looks silly, but i think that is the only choice (without using a union list) `vars<SomeType, '--YYY-'>('--YYY-', ... ` (-- and - can be optimized).

Comment: Yeah, I figured it would be something like that, and I totally get it. :-) The other option is an intermediary function (which really isn't all that expensive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...without adding an extra parameter like `vars<T, Scope>(...`

With that limitation, it's impossible. `UnprefixKeys` needs to have a string literal type to work with, but if you can't add a second generic type parameter to `vars`, the type of `scope` will be `string`, not `SomeLiteralType extends string`. To do what you want, you need the latter.

If you really can't add the type parameter, that's the answer.

---

<s>I'm guessing</s> You've confirmed that you want to avoid the second type parameter because you need to specify the `T` parameter explicitly, and that would mean you couldn't make the second type parameter implicit (inferred from usage), so you'd have to type the constant twice (once as a type argument, once as a runtime argument).

To work around that, you can write a function that produces `vars` functions for a particular scope, like this:

```typescript
function makeVars<Scope extends string>(scope: Scope) {
    return function vars<T>(vars: UnprefixKeys<T, Scope>): T {
        return <T>null;
    };
}
```

Now the usage is:

```typescript
const varsYYY = makeVars("--YYY-");
varsYYY<SomeType>({
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
});
```

Or if you like:

```typescript
makeVars("--YYY-")<SomeType>({
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
});
```

Trying to use an invalid key in the object still fails as desired:

```typescript
varsYYY<SomeType>({
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    q: 42, // <== Error here as desired
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=31&ssc=1&pln=26&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYGsCmA1VAnAZwB4BlCOAB00UwA8pMwATAxAqPGMAcwD4AKAuSoAuRGUqYAlIgDeAWABQiFYjyYoIPElCRYCRADd8xACoDjhMQFUwFdcBi0A0pgCeZgDTjhmXlLFTOSVVULUNLSQiczAQABs4gG4Q1QBfZMVUpSUoNypxOGRMUzzqAF5g5VUAIgBaWoBNJtrUarFY5AAjTDwM0LrG5s62xA7u3qV07MUAehnEAHU4PHQCJXIwdiMTJobECrQsXEJ+Ad3a6qkMywJd0kLi0oEFKpVUMQBGTxSVTrEAJm+mSu0zmiAAgnECHBEAB3ZarJSHHAmU71c6Xe5FEpUZ4-RDvRBffF-RCAyYgxRKMEAUTweGWBNYTEwBBg6iYShudxIDxxfn4L1ChOJr0QpPJYoAjmIACyAxBgohlCp0hl4RAACx61FQzNZ7MwnOBGWp81y+RAsDiMFgrMQ-Cg2rccIRUhypUQtnsmEcLncRGcNHojBYiAACgyqHhcq43N5I76nMGGMxWOxODxePtEEG6KmwwADAAkskTftSpa4wB6EdShfxAH4I-ixM5TYoLdRvQ4nHGvBHe7QU6H0xwuHwc0LVABtINcRBYNxwYCIIJ6r12IdxwMJoe8AC6gTnB4y6SAA)

Comment: Hang on, I've accidentally repeated `scope`. I'll fix it.

Comment: Okay, fixed it now. :-)

Comment: Thank you. Yes i thought about a wrapper too. I think i pass it 2 times with one function, one as a generic for typing and one for runtime usage.